# using first row as heading in data frame

Tags: python, pandas

```
u_cols = ["Inv. Date","Customer Name","Model","Variant"]
users=pd.read_csv('5ch.xls.Sheet1.cvs', sep=',', names=u_cols)
```

There are times when I do not know the list of column headings. Is  there any way to tell the data frame to use the first row as names?

Comment: don't specify the names: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#csv-text-files

Comment: There are cases with the first row being the title and the headers are on row 2 or 3. Is it possible to still read it without using names?

Comment: use ``skiprows``. It pays to actually read the documentation, their are a lot of options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does so by default. The `header` parameter to `read_csv` defaults to 0 (the first row of the given CSV file), unless you pass the `names` argument, which you have.

In your case, I don't see why you can't simply write

```
users=pd.read_csv('5ch.xls.Sheet1.cvs')
```

given that `sep` defaults to a comma.